# convert API response to json

Tags: python, json

I get the following response using Flickr API photo.search

```
jsonFlickrApi({"photos":{"page":1,"pages":3786,"perpage":100,"total":"378562","photo":[{"id":"48197008707","owner":"22430972@N05","secret":"36b279092c","server":"65535","farm":66,"title":"Callum and our Cat friend, 5th June 2019.","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"48196846446","owner":"156701458@N02","secret":"d650bc4c35","server":"65535","farm":66,"title":"\u2606 Post Nr. 294 SENSE \u2013 Celestinas Kids, Parke Ave. & Posh and Tm:.Creation \u2606","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0}...{"id":"48196265577","owner":"61762095@N08","secret":"db8d31c2b2","server":"65535","farm":66,"title":"190702_028.jpg","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0}]},"stat":"ok"})
```

I added ... in midddle because response is too long to share all,anyway How can I covert this to a JSON object (dict that contains a list of dicts in "photo". If I use `json.dumps` directly it get messed up i.e treated as a single string

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: @VictorRuiz I use scrapy request (using my API key) to get JSON

Comment: Do you mean the whole `jsonFlickrApi({...})` is a string?

Comment: @Andyk. yes, for example in `scrapy shell ...` `response.text` it opens in a text pad, containing the same as I posted (much longer ofcourse)

Comment: Is not ```dumps```. Its ```loads``` to convert string into JSON (https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads)

Comment: @VictorRuiz `di=json.loads(response.text[14:-1))` (removing "jsonFlickrApi(") works, but I feel this isn't good programming right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know for sure the text will start with "jsonFlickrApi(", you can parse it as such. You can change variable `start` for some other starting string.

Regular Expression is a right tool if you need more advanced matching tools

```
str = r"""jsonFlickrApi({"photos":{"page":1,"pages":3786,"perpage":100,"total":"378562","photo":[{"id":"48197008707","owner":"22430972@N05","secret":"36b279092c","server":"65535","farm":66,"title":"Callum and our Cat friend, 5th June 2019.","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"48196846446","owner":"156701458@N02","secret":"d650bc4c35","server":"65535","farm":66,"title":"\u2606 Post Nr. 294 SENSE \u2013 Celestinas Kids, Parke Ave. & Posh and Tm:.Creation \u2606","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0}...{"id":"48196265577","owner":"61762095@N08","secret":"db8d31c2b2","server":"65535","farm":66,"title":"190702_028.jpg","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0}]},"stat":"ok"})"""

start = len("jsonFlickrApi("); 

json.loads(str[start: -1]);
```

**Update for re**

Since it is a response from other's API, I would assume the json object is valid. The pattern is simple with re too

```
str = r"""jsonFlickrApi({"photos":{"page":1,"pages":3786,"perpage":100,"total":"378562","photo":[{"id":"48197008707","owner":"22430972@N05","secret":"36b279092c","server":"65535","farm":66,"title":"Callum and our Cat friend, 5th June 2019.","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"48196846446","owner":"156701458@N02","secret":"d650bc4c35","server":"65535","farm":66,"title":"\u2606 Post Nr. 294 SENSE \u2013 Celestinas Kids, Parke Ave. & Posh and Tm:.Creation \u2606","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0}...{"id":"48196265577","owner":"61762095@N08","secret":"db8d31c2b2","server":"65535","farm":66,"title":"190702_028.jpg","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0}]},"stat":"ok"})"""


jsonStr = re.findall("{.*}",str)[0]
json.loads(jsonStr)
```

Comment: I think regex is a better way to do it since, I don't know when the dictionary will start

Comment: I have updated the answer to parse with `re` matching

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract the JSON formatted data and then use `json.loads`:

```py
import re
import json

text = 'jsonFlickrApi({"photos":[{"id":"A", "title":"Hello"}, {"id":"B", "title":"World"}]})'

result = re.fullmatch('[ ]*jsonFlickrApi[ ]*\((.+?)\)[ ]*', text)
print(json.loads(result.group(1)))
```

Output:

```
{'photos': [{'id': 'A', 'title': 'Hello'}, {'id': 'B', 'title': 'World'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting the body as a string
Use json.parse(response)
And it should solve the problem

Comment: module json has no attribute parse